# How to insert in a blog sharing links to visitors Tweet, Facebook and so on social networks?

Tags: asp.net, web-development, web-applications, social-networking, social-media

I am developing a web blog using ASP.NET, but I guess that the tech details like this, here, is not important.
My aim is to insert in every post I create those nice buttons to the social networks account of my visitors so that they can quote or post the link to the blog entry in their space.

How can I do this?
I guess it also de3pend on the social network I want to use. Lets say, now, that I want to have links to Facebook, Tweet and Google circle accounts.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

A quick googling of "social button code" brought up [this bloggers post](http://machoarts.com/share-button-codes-of-facebook-twitter-delicious-digg-and-stumbleupon) containing the code for all major services.

You could also use a service like [AddThis.com](http://www.addthis.com/), which will allow you to select the social site buttons and the way they will be displayed. There are many services like this out there, so if this one isn't to your taste, try another, you are sure to find one to your liking.

One last note, before using one of the "services" you may want to read this informative article on the subject (included in it are links to the most popular social media buttons generators).

^^ note: unfortunately I am restricted to posting only two hyperlinks, so if you want to read the last article mentioned just google "frankkoehl.com free open source alternatives" - it should be on the first page of results.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://tosbourn.com/2011/07/development/the-big-three-social-codes/) are the big three codes, I would advise against using services that add several to your site at once as you cannot control the code behind them and some of them are coded so poorly that many unnecessary calls are required to load everything.